# Run server and client application coding with java

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming, client-server

Thank everyone to see my problem.
I'd like to explain my problem on Socket with java.
Using socket ,one for server to waiting for connection from client, the other for client to connect with server. **THERE ARE TWO PROBLEM~~**

(1)

+++After they all connect with each other, the two side can exchange messages to each other.  I'have already finished the two Application code with server and client with each own main **THREAD**,but I can't let them communicate with each other. I use windows command to run this two file .class. I run server first ,and then I run client. They can't communicate with each other.  I Want to know whether this is a problem about congestion.If I establish a another thread ,this problem could be solved??

(2)   I attempt to run this two application on two eclipse,in other words each eclipse run one application.  Why this problem can be solved??

(3)HERE is my code for client:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class CC {
    public static void main(String args[]){
         Socket   client=null;
         DataInputStream in=null;
         DataOutputStream out=null;
         try{
              client=new Socket("127.0.0.1",2060);
              in=new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());
              out=new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
              System.out.println("You are a client,you send message to server");
              Scanner cin=new Scanner(System.in);
              while(true){
                String send=null,receive=null;
                System.out.println("Please input Client message sending to server!");
                send=cin.nextLine();
                out.writeUTF(send);
                receive=in.readUTF();
                System.out.println("Message from Server is:"+receive);
                Thread.sleep(500);  
              } 
         }
    
         catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("break！"+e);
        
         }
        
   }
```

}

Here is my code for server

```
 import java.util.*;
 import java.io.*;
 import java.net.*;
 public class SS {
  public  static void main(String args[]){
      ServerSocket socketServer=null;
      DataInputStream  in=null;
      DataOutputStream out=null;
      Socket server;
      try{
          socketServer=new ServerSocket(2060);
      }
      catch(Exception e1){
          System.out.println("can't estblish socketServer "+e1);  
      }
      try{
          Scanner cin=new Scanner(System.in);
          System.out.println("you are server ,please send message to client");
          server=socketServer.accept();  
          in=new DataInputStream(server.getInputStream());
          out=new DataOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());
          while(true){
              String send=null,receive=null;
              receive=in.readUTF();
              System.out.println("get message from client is "+receive);
              System.out.println("send message from client");
              send=cin.nextLine();
              out.writeUTF(send);
         }
      }
      catch(Exception e){
         System.out.println("break！ "+e);
      }
  }      
}
```

Comment: "After they all connect with each other, the two side can exchange messages to each other" and "but I can't let them communicate with each other" are conflicting. What do you see on the console of each of these programs? Also, you don't need a `Scanner` in the server code, unless you want to send input from Server to Client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server and client code deadlocks.

In the client code you have written `send=cin.nextLine();`, which blocks until more input is available. In the server code you have written `receive=in.readUTF();` which too blocks until input is available.

That is, immediately after a connection is established, both the server and the client expects the other to send something which results in a deadlock and both of them wait indefinitely.

You have to make sure that either the server or the client first sends some output before waiting to accept input.

Comment: thank you,I have solve this problem under my friends.Because I have run this application before,the port has been occupied.Then I run this application for the second time,this result these two application can not transfer message. These two Application is totally right.

Answer (score 0):

thank you,I have solve this problem under my friends.Because I have run this application before,the port has been occupied.Then I run this application for the second time,this result these two application can not transfer message. These two Application is totally right.